# Access member of State from instance of Stateful Widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have `StatefulWidget` instance.

However I want to access the method of `State` from the instance of `StatefulWidget`.

It might be very simple and basic for flutter, but for the beginner of Stateful/State systen, it is a bit complex.

```
class MainBody extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _MainBodyState createState() => _MainBodyState();
}
class _MainBodyState extends State<MainBody>{
  _MainBodyState();

  void connectMainBody(){
    print("ConnectMainBody");
  }


class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Widget mainBody;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    mainBody = new MainBody();
    mainBody.connectMainBody()// how can I access this method?? 
  }
```

---

My idea was completely wrong.

https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-communication-between-widgets-f5590230df1e

I checked this page and learned.

`How to access from Parent to Child.`

By giving parameters to Child's Constructor.

`How to access from Child to Parent.`

By using callback function given to Child from Parent in advance.

I think I should learn about GlobalKey next.

Thank you very much for your advice.

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually? do you still want to set different `body` in your `Scaffold`?

Comment: That is not feasible and is anti-pattern to begin with. We'll need to know more about your use-case

Comment: Honestly say I was a bit confused... I googled around and understood. It is not recommended to access  from Parent to Child method. I am thinking another way.

Comment: Thank you @pskink, I have bumped into the many problems, and try and error many things for now.